# How to multiple record audio in outfile and show list view?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-audiorecord

My code is able to record audio and show list view for only one but I want to more audio record in outfile and  show list view.

```
 OUTPUT_FILE=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/" + name + ".3gpp";
    Log.d("Files", "Path: " + OUTPUT_FILE);
    File f = new File(OUTPUT_FILE);        
     myList = new ArrayList<String>();
     myList.add(f.getName());

   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, myList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            try
            {
                playRecording();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem and correct code is shown below:

```
myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        file = new File( "/sdcard/"+name+"/");
        file.mkdirs();
        File list[] = file.listFiles();

        for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
        {
           myList.add( list[i].getName() );
        }
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
           ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, myList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```